# Firefox canvas upload bug

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, crop

I've encountered a rather annoying bug, whilst adjusting http://croppic.net/ way of cropping images - rather than cropping them on the server side, I do it on the front end (renders them faster and their sizes stop becoming an issue).

The problem is that my method works perfectly fine in Chrome and IE, but nothing else; both Firefox and Safari support Filereader API (I've already checked that). For cropper to work, users have to upload the same image twice - where the first time it will be blank, and the second time it will work perfectly.

Apologies for not tidy code, been hacking and slashing it for the last couple of hours.

**The Code is:**

```
var crop_canvas,
left = Math.abs( parseInt( that.img.css('left') ) ), 
top =  Math.abs( parseInt( that.img.css('top') ) ),
width = that.imgInitW;
height = that.imgInitH;    
crop_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

var secondW = that.imgW;
var secondH = that.imgH;

crop_canvas.width = secondW;
crop_canvas.height = secondH;

image_target = new Image();
image_target.src = that.imgUrl;
var newImg = new Image();  
crop_canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image_target, 0, 0, secondW, secondH);
newImg.src = crop_canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
//starts breaking here
var finalImg = new Image();
var new_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
new_canvas.width = that.objW;
new_canvas.height = that.objH;
var img_last = new_canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(newImg, left, top,  that.objW, that.objH, 0, 0,that.objW, that.objH);
finalImg.src = img_last.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Comment: you need to wait for the image to load (`image_target.onload = doMagic`)

Comment: Tried to do that, then tried to do that on the second image too. Same effect, but can try to do it again. I even used `window.open(image.src, "_blank")` to see which images were loading correctly

Comment: You draw the image before its loaded. Opening it in a new tap to see if the image is there does not help here.

Comment: **that.imgURL** is a parameter that is already encoded to Base64, so I literally just added an alert to onload, and still the same issue.

Comment: Mmm can u update code with the inload stuff?

Comment: I've added onload to every image with alerts - started to work; doesn't work with console.logs; but I'll just add a timer or something. Thanks though!

Comment: Okay you don't need to add alerts you need to add the rest of your code in the onload callback

Comment: There is no code for the first image, since I don't need to draw a canvas for it, I've added the code for the second image to be the draw canvas code, but if I add the last code as a draw canvas one - nothing works again.

Answer (score 0):

**Roland** was right, I needed to use an **onload** callback, but on the last image.
I also set a timeout method, that fully waits for the image to load:

```
var finalImg = new Image();
finalImg.onload = setTimeout(makingImg, 2000);

function makingImg(){
   new_canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(newImg, left, top, that.objW, that.objH, 0, 0,that.objW, that.objH);
   finalImg.src = new_canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
   if (that.options.imgEyecandy)
   that.imgEyecandy.hide();

   that.destroy();

   that.obj.append('<img class="croppedImg" src="' + finalImg.src + '">');

                 if (that.options.outputUrlId !== '') { $('#' + that.options.outputUrlId).val(response.url); }

                 that.croppedImg = that.obj.find('.croppedImg');

                 that.init();

                 that.hideLoader();
                 that.afterCrop();
 }

}
```